# Why do I need to use double curly Brackets in my RegEx?

Tags: regex, xslt, saxon

I'm running a little regular expression in one of my xsl-transformations (`xsl:analyze-string`) and came across this effect that made me rather uncomfortable because I didn't really find any explanation...

I was searching for Non-Breaking-Spaces and En-Spaces, so I used the `\p{Z}` construct. According to many examples in the XSLT 2.0 Programmers Reference by Michael Kay, this should work. RegExBuddy also approves :)

Now my SaxonHE9.4N tells me

> Error in regular expression: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: expected ({)

After several trials and errors I simply doubled the Brackets `\p{{Z}}` ... and it worked!? But this time RegExBuddy disapproves!

Can someone give me an explanation of this effect? I couldn't find anything satisfying on the internet...

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I tried the same thing inside of a `replace()` function and the double bracket version didn't work. I had to do it with single brackets!

Comment: I don't know `saxon` but in some regex flavor you could just use `\pZ` without the brackets. You could have a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an attribute value template, curly braces are special syntax indicating an XPath expression to be evaluated. If you want literal curly braces, [you have to escape them by doubling](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates):

> An attribute value template consists of an alternating sequence of
>   fixed parts and variable parts. A variable part consists of an XPath
>   expression enclosed in curly brackets ({}). A fixed part may contain
>   any characters, except that **a left curly bracket must be written as {{
>   and a right curly bracket must be written as }}**.
>
> > Note:
> >
> > An expression within a variable part may contain an unescaped curly
> >     bracket within a StringLiteral XP or within a comment.

Not all attributes are AVTs, but [the regex attribute of analyze-string is](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string):

> Note:
>
> Because the regex attribute is an attribute value template, **curly
>   brackets within the regular expression must be doubled.** For example,
>   to match a sequence of one to five characters, write regex=".{{1,5}}".
>   For regular expressions containing many curly brackets it may be more
>   convenient to use a notation such as
>   regex="{'[0-9]{1,5}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}'}", or to use a variable.

(Emphasis added, in both quotes.)

Comment: @OP: P.S. In regard to RegexBuddy's dis/approval: when you use `regex="\p{{Z}}"`, you are supplying the regexp `\p{Z}` (with appropriate escaping). If you give RegexBuddy the same regexp `\p{Z}`, it approves. So RegexBuddy agrees with XSLT about this regexp.